# Javascript function - What's wrong with it?

Tags: javascript

bit confused on what's wrong with this function as it's not functioning correctly. (excuse the pun) New to javascript and programming in general too.

Basically what it's supposed to do is change two images on a page based on a list selection however it defaults to option2's images even though option1 is selected. Am I going about this correctly?

```
function check(){
if (value = "option1"){
document.getElementById("image_1").src="http://www.website.com/image1.jpg";
document.getElementById("image_2").src="http://www.website.com/image1-1.jpg";
}

else 
if (value = "option2"){
document.getElementById("image_1").src="http://www.website.com/image2.jpg";
document.getElementById("image_2").src="http://www.website.com/image2_2.jpg";
}
}
```

Edit: spelling.

Comment: Use == for comparison instead of =

Comment: Just curious, did you write that code yourself or found it somewhere? Did you learn the concept of variables/functions before starting to write?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard. Wrote it myself but replaced my data with option1/image_1 etc. Just slowly teaching myself at the moment getting the basics down.

Comment: @Cat key is patience then, try to understand the code given in the answer you accepted not just copy and use it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didnt pass parameter to your `check()` function, and you are using assignment operator( `=` ) instead of equality check operator( `==` ) , do:

```
function check(value){
  if (value == "option1"){
    document.getElementById("image_1").src="http://www.website.com/image1.jpg";
    document.getElementById("image_2").src="http://www.website.com/image1-1.jpg";
  }

  else if (value == "option2"){
    document.getElementById("image_1").src="http://www.website.com/image2.jpg";
    document.getElementById("image_2").src="http://www.website.com/image2_2.jpg";
  }
}
```

Comment: one thing that I don't understand is why in OP's function, option2 will be the default.

Comment: @grape_mao both `if` statements will evaluate to `true` (assignment successful), so the second block will reassign the values assigned in the first block.

Comment: @Pavlo here is if...else if...the second one won't even get evaluated at all.

Comment: @grape_mao I have just check it and you are right. Probably it's OP's inaccuracy.

Answer (score -1):

you haven't passed the value to the function so it's going into else by default.

Comment: Appears to be a troll, don't take it personally but your answer also is not very complete. See [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19207052/447356) for example of a complete and helpful answer.

Comment: Your answer was neither complete (the `==` part was missing), nor did it explain why exactly JavaScript went into the `else` part.